# rvest returns empty list for html table

Tags: html, r, rvest

I really can't get my head around this problem and I would be grateful for any piece of advice that you could give me.

I am trying to scrape the Bitcoin implied volatility index (BitVol) on this website:
https://t3index.com/indices/bit-vol/

It is possible to show the raw values in the Chart via this button and by clicking on "View data table":

[image: Bitcoin BitVol Chart]

The id of the relevant html table is "highcharts-data-table-1":
[image: Bitcoin BitVol Table]

I have used the rvest package to scrape this table. This is what I got so far:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url5 <- "https://t3index.com/indices/bit-vol/"

output <- url(url5) %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="highcharts-data-table-1"]//table[1]') %>% 
  html_table()
```

The code runs smoothly without returning any errors but still the query returns an empty list in the variable *output* despite the fact that I have followed the recommendations in this article as well:
[rvest returning empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162192/rvest-returning-empty-list)

This is the current R Version that I am using:

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "0.3"

$year
[1] "2020"

$month
[1] "10"

$day
[1] "10"

$`svn rev`
[1] "79318"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"

$nickname
[1] "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I bet the data and chart are loaded via javascript in the browser. You'd probably need rselenium to simulate a browser running javascript to scrape that data.

Comment: Since there's a button on the chart menu to Download CSV, it might be easier to track down what that triggers and just read the downloaded data.

Comment: Both suggestions are quite helpful. Thanks! Any idea how to interact with javascript via rvest in order to read the revelant html table?

Comment: You need to take a look at rselenium.